# Is there a numpy.there?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I was wondering whether there is a opposite of `numpy.where` (going from booleans to indices) which goes from indices to booleans; for example `numpy.there`.

A possible implementation could use scipy's sparse matrices:

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
numpy_there = lambda there, n: numpy.array(
  csr_matrix((
    [1]*len(there),
    there,
    [0, len(there)]
  ),
  shape=(1,n),
  dtype=numpy.bool
).todense())[0,:]

numpy_there([1,4,6,7,12], 15)

array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

But obviously, this requires scipy and is quite verbose, whereas given `numpy.where` I would also expect a `numpy.there`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with [`np.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) to simulate such a behaviour, like so -

```
def numpy_there(A,val):
    return np.in1d(np.arange(val),A)
```

Sample run -

```
In [14]: A
Out[14]: array([ 1,  4,  6,  7, 12])

In [15]: numpy_there(A,15)
Out[15]: 
array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

You can use a bit more verbose implementation using initialization with boolean `False` values and then assigning `True` values at `A` indexed positions, like so -

```
def numpy_there_v2(A,val):
    out = np.zeros(val,dtype=bool)
    out[A] = 1
    return out
```

Comment: I won't accept this answer, because it seems like np.in1d makes the solution O(M * N) for M the number of trues and N the array dimension. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The 2nd version is the dense array equivalent of your sparse code.

Comment: @Herbert And `O(M*N)` would be the memory complexity? Are you looking for a sparse array as output or a dense version of it?

Comment: The `zeros` approach is much faster than the `in1d`, and faster than the sparse version.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah I had that gut feeling too! Thanks for timing those!

Comment: At best, the in1d can have O(  val*log(val)  +  len(A) * log(len(A))) (sorting both first and then a linear walk through both arrays incrementing at least one index). -- except if the sorting algorithm used is biased towards already sorted lists, such that those are sorted in O(n), then the in1d-approach is O(val), but I doubt that.

Comment: @Herbert AFAIK `np.in1d` isn't a looping operation on Python level. These are NumPy operations that are optimized at C level. So, you can't have a runtime complexity level number on Python level.

Comment: @Divakar I highly doubt that the size's of python-level objects have no impact on the runtime when applied to C-code.

Comment: @Herbert Well we are not dealing with Python Objects. Those are totally different things altogether. We are using `np.arange(val)` that creates a Numpy array of the same datatype `int` for all its elements and `A` apparently is also all `ints` as well. Being of the same datatype, NumPy can operate in a highly optimized vectorized manner.

Comment: Yes, I get that it's highly optimized and 'vectorized' (which is a fancy word for for-loops in C? since I only see one core working at a time when running numpy-code). But this would account for a constant factor speedup, not a difference in runtime complexity. That is, a list of size n becomes an numpy.array of size n which than still takes O(n log(n)) to sort, even when the sorting is implemented in C.

Comment: @Herbert Yes, you can think of NumPy as being performed at C level, so the "O" of runtime complexity with it would be a different one as compared to the "O" when you would use a loop at Python level, right? If you implement this whole thing in C, then I guess the "O"s would be comparable and speedup and all those performance metrics could be compared.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a loop implemented in C and that same loop implemented in Python both should have the sample runtime complexity, even though Python may be a constant factor slower, at some point an O(n) Python implementation is going to be faster then a O(n log(n)) C implementation.